# One to Many & Many To One Relation In Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**I have 2 Tables**

1. Users
2. Messages

**And the Structure of Tables:**

Users:

[image]

Messages:

[image]

Now see there are number of users in Users Table and their messages are stored in Messages table identifying by sender_id and receiver_id

How can I make One-To-Many and Many To One Relationship between these two tables or create this SQL Schema using Doctrine/Annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="messages")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5000, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $text;


    /**
     * Author of the comment
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $sender;

   /**
     * 
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $reciever;
```

Comment: Its should show 2 Relation Strings from User to Message in Design Mode, But its showing just one